# Mostrar registros repetidos que contengan una celda vacía en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
id_usuario  | idioma     | certificado
________________________________________
12          | Español    | Si
12          | Francés    |
12          | Alemán     | Si
13          | Español    |
13          | Inglés     |
14          | Inglés     | Si
14          | Alemán     |
15          | Inglés     | Si
16          | Italiano   |
```

Cuando deseo mostrar los usuarios que al menos tengan un idioma certificado realizo la siguiente consulta:

`SELECT DISTINCT(id_usuario) FROM myTable where certificado='Si'`

Y el resultado:

```
id_usuario  | 
_____________
12          | 
14          | 
15          |
```

Pero ahora quiero obtener los usuarios que no tienen ningún idioma certificado, lo he intentado haciendo esta consulta:

`SELECT DISTINCT(id_usuario) FROM myTable where certificado!='Si'`

Pero me salen estos resultados:

```
id_usuario  | 
_____________
12          | 
13          | 
14          | 
16          |
```

Y yo quiero obtener esto:

```
id_usuario  | 
_____________
13          | 
16          |
```

¿Cómo realizo el cambio en la consulta?

Agradeceré su respuesta.

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes comparar la cantidad con el total de regitros con el "si"que sea menor a 1 o ==0

ejemplo

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id_usuario) FROM myTable AS Table where (select Count(*) from myTable where 
         myTable.id_usuario=Table.id_usuario and myTable.certificado='Si')<1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, solo habría que modificar a ``myTable.certificado='Si'``

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id_usuario) FROM myTable WHERE (certificado != 'Si' OR certificado IS NULL)
```

Al no tener registros el campo es nulo. Así que podrías incluir la condición si es nulo)
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Emplea una subconsulta y evita hacer el filtrado a través de la comparación del número de registros.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(idUsuario) idUsuario 
FROM myTable 
WHERE certificado != "Si" 
AND idUsuario NOT IN (SELECT idUsuario FROM myTable WHERE certificado = "Si");
```

Al final obtiene justamente la información que requieres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]